# local variables are not being passed to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my view code in which rendering a partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'foo' , :locals => { :user => @current_user } %>
```

and Here is my 'foo' partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for :foobar %>
<%= user.id %>
....
<% end %>
```

but i run into this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0xac52574>:0xb58178dc>
```

P.S: on rails 4 , ruby 1.9.3

Comment: The `@variables` are shared between action, view and partials, so you should be able to use directly `<%= @current_user.id %>` in your partial ;)

Comment: MrYoshiiji's answer is right. But I am wondering why you need a @current_user variable. Never seen that before.. I think a method which returns your current user directly, would be much more convenient. Am I right? :-)

Comment: @Mattherick is right, @Pooya you should create a helper method `current_user` that returns the current user logged in. (Most of Sign-In gems have this `current_user()` method, if you have you own Sign-In system, you can write your own: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-current_user )

Comment: Try this: `<%= render partial: 'foo' , { :user => @current_user } %>` or even `<%= render partial: 'foo' , :user => @current_user %>`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I'm just testing the passing the locals, I'm familiar with devise! non of the solutions worked , still getting that error ! maybe this is a kind of rails 4 bug!